# How to write xsd schema to generate wsdl operations reusing same output type?

Tags: soap, xsd, wsdl

I am generating WSDL file from XSD definition using `org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.DefaultWsdl11Definition` and `org.springframework.xml.xsd.commons.CommonsXsdSchemaCollection`.

This is definition of response type in XSD schema:

```
<xs:element name="MyReusableResponse">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:documentation>
      <![CDATA[
        My reusable response
      ]]>
    </xs:documentation>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
       <xs:element name="value1" type="xs:string" />
       <xs:element name="value2" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

generated WSDL file then automatically contains operation `MyReusable`:

```
<wsdl:operation name="MyReusable">
  <wsdl:output message="tns:MyReusableResponse" name="MyReusableResponse" />
</wsdl:operation>
```

But I would like to have multiple operations using same response element as an output.

```
<wsdl:operation name="MyReusable">
  <wsdl:output message="tns:MyReusableResponse" name="MyReusableResponse" />
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="OtherOperationUsingSameRequest">
  <wsdl:output message="tns:MyReusableResponse" name="MyReusableResponse" />
</wsdl:operation>
```

Is there a way to define custom operation from XSD? Or somehow bind same response type to multiple operations?